# How to deploy optional package shared libraries in weblogic

Tags: java, oracle, shared-libraries, weblogic, weblogic11g

I've got a dozen ear files, which load the same set of jars for each component deployed as an enterprise application in weblogic... I want to move these dependencies to a "shared library" (optional package) jar file. I've done the leg work of moving these artifacts to a jar file and added MANIFEST.MF with `Extension-Name` as specified in

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/libraries.html

Now I need to deploy this "shared library" optional package to weblogic 11g, before deploying the enterprise application components, which reference them. Currently deployment is done using a bunch of wlst jython scripts in offline mode, which does a full install of the domain on the filesystem. How do I deploy shared libraries in offline mode?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to deploy shared libs in offline mode, only online, so I re-wrote the deployment scripts using wlst tool. I deploy datasources, jms, non-library-dependent apps in offline mode, then bring up the admin node and deploy libraries in online mode using standard deploy function in weblogic. You can google oracle docs on this, they describe the function and arguments that can be passed quite well. The once the libs are deployed, you deploy the apps (ears or whatever) in online mode, using hte same deploy mechanism from wlst minus the library argument, because applications are not libraries.

Some helpful resources:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/understanding.html#1052661

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/deploy.html#1020594

Comment: sample wlst syntax in py http://wlstbyexamples.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/deployment-script-using-wlst.html#.WWTYjhMrJ9O